# Can not use modPow() on int? (Java)

Tags: java, math, cryptography, modulo

My Code:

```
public static void verschluesseln(int m) {
    if(m < n) {
            int c =  m.modPow((int) n, oeffentlicherSchluessel[0]);
    }
```

Error:

```
.java:51: error: int cannot be dereferenced
            int c =  m.modPow((int) n, oeffentlicherSchluessel[0]);
                      ^
```

This did run in another project of mine. This is why I am heavily confused by this error.

Comment: No, it didn't. You may not call methods on primitive types. modPow() is a method of the BigInteger class. You needs an instance of BigInteger to call it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow-java.math.BigInteger-java.math.BigInteger-

Comment: `int` is a primitive and no primitive has a method in Java. You might have been thinking of another language e.g. C# has this.

Comment: Or, perhaps you wrote your own modPow method just for ints in your other program.

Comment: @JamesKPolk You would still not be able to call it on an `int` as in the displayed code.

Answer (score 2):

[modPow](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,java.math.BigInteger)) is `BigInteger` method, you can't use it with int. It also receives `BigInteger` as parameters, not `int`

```
BigInteger c = BigInteger.valueOf(m).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(n), BigInteger.valueOf(oeffentlicherSchluessel[0]));
```